# Greyscale only on login screen - Big Sur 11.4

Tags: macbook-pro, big-sur

Here are the specs:

```
MacBookAir9,1
13-inch 2020
1.1 GHz Dual-Core Intel i3
8GB 3733 MHz LPDDR4X
Big Sur 11.4
```

On first boot, the login screen is black/white (like greyscale). Once I log in, everything goes back to normal. I tried safe mode and the issue was not present, leading me to believe it is a software issue.

I've done research and tried the following things:

Filevault is not enabled

Desktop picture is default

Accessibility completely reset in terminal

Checked the console and looked at all errors in kernels, even deleting all my 3rd party extensions found in ~/Library/Extensions

Attempted to reinstall Big Sur via recovery and was greeted with this error:

```
The operation couldn't be completed. (com.apple.BuildInfo.preflight.error error 21.)
```

I don't know what to do about this error or if it is relevant to this issue. Have a feeling it may be.

The last thing downloaded was an application for 3D printer, which didn't work (in terms of the printer and application). Right before that there was EV3 Classroom; a LEGO robotics program installed for their 9 year old.

I can always just full restore the disk but I really want to try and figure out how to solve this. I have found guides on how to find 3rd party extensions from console and when it gets to the "delete damaged extensions" step, they never explain how they found the damaged extensions. On the scan I get nearly 5,000 entries and I don't know what to even look for.

I hope this is ample info to get an idea of what my issue is. I appreciate taking time to read all this. I'm hoping to get this solved quickly.

Comment: Do you still want to reinstall via recovery?

Comment: @Ant if possible, because I have a feeling that could solve the issue. But was just seeing if anyone else have seen this. I found one thread on reddit and the 2 solutions were "turn off FileVault" and "don't change your background to a picture off the internet"